# Empty string from JS is not binding to nullable GUID in .Net Core 3.1 web api

Tags: angular, .net-core

I am working with an Angular client side that consumes .Net Core Web API endpoints. I have just recently updated the API to .Net Core 3.1, and the empty string parameters from the client side is not binding to the nullable Guid in the server side. The receiving parameter in the API always ends up as null as a result, while previously in .Net Core 2.2, everything is working fine. Setting the empty string as null works properly though.

For example:

```
SomeObject { id: '', state: 2 } is now translating to null even though the id parameter is a nullable Guid.
```

Comment: Could you provide the endpoint's function signature and the way the query is initiated from angular?

Comment: Here are the details: https://pastebin.com/g8dPVd1g. As for the query, I am using Swashbuckle in the API and ng-openapi-gen in Angular. It is pretty straightforward, because I can verify that the client is sending the correct body to the API when looking at Postman or at browser console. The request body is: { id: "4d7d1885-fa3b-40e8-2bf1-08d8807a338e", anotherId: "" }

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm experiencing a similar issue.